# Trying to predict binding to lipopolysaccharide (LPS)

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a bunch of PDB files containing the structures of novel peptides, and I want to see if any of them will bind to LPS via computational prediction. I could do molecular dynamics, but that requires a lot of computing power unfortunately. Any other good options?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One easy idea is to take the PDB of a peptide you are confident binds to LPS and then claim that peptides that look structurally similar also have a shot of binding LPS. This is a semi-qualitative argument.

As an example, I found w/ a quick search this peptide sequence which binds LPS: `KNYSSSISSIHAC`
(source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20816904)

Then to get the predicted structure of that sequence I used PEP-Fold which is an online tool
(source: http://mobyle.rpbs.univ-paris-diderot.fr/cgi-bin/portal.py#forms::PEP-FOLD3)

I think you can download from the job I submitted 
(http://mobyle.rpbs.univ-paris-diderot.fr/data/jobs/PEP-FOLD3/C24081178740978)

After you download the PDB, you want to find the RMSD of each of your peptide structures to this PDB, and low RMSDs could represent LPS binding, but its definitely not definitive and unclear where to draw the line of "close enough".

This is all very wishy-washy, and as you say, molecular dynamics is a better option. You might also consider just sequence alignments w/ peptides that do bind LPS w/out worrying about 3D.

You might get better responses at Biostars or some other forum since your question is not coding based